# How do we create custom getters and setters, and what’s the advantage of doing so in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, getter-setter

What is the reason of using custom getters and setters in an application.

Answer (score 3):

That's fairly very simple

First let me show you a sample of how getters and setters in Dart look like, which is essentially the language behind Flutter

```
class Foo {
    
  // Creating a field/instance variable
  String _fooName; //Keeping it private always
    
  // Using the getter
  String get foo_name {
//We can do something else here, like saving the variable somewhere and then returning it to the caller function
    return _fooName;// private variable return for use in outside class
  }
    
  // Using the setter method
  set foo_name (String name) {
    // We can do something else, like update another variable based on fooName
    this._fooName = name;//private variable being assigned new value
  }
}
```

From the name, setters are involved in setting the values to an instance variable in an object oriented programming paradigm whereas getters are involved in getting the value of an instance variable

Now you would ask why not return the instance variable directly and why having such a roundabout approach to setting and getting the value

Well the answer is while getting as well as setting, we might want to do some other operation too other than just setting or getting the value and it's always better not to give admin access to the variables and that's why they are private so as to promote consistency within the objects accessing the field

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of preference, but you really shouldn't needlessly create one for a single field

https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-wrap-a-field-in-a-getter-and-setter-unnecessarily

One use case for creating a setter would be to perform some type of validation

For a getter, it'd be useful for a calculated field based on other properties, rather than a single property alone